# Capistrano 3: undefined method 'colorize' for :location:Symbol on first deploy attempt

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to set up deployment via ssh using capistrano 3.2.1 from a Windows machine to remote host. But on first run I get the following error:

*cap production deploy --trace --verbose*

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host #&lt;Capistrano::Configuration::Server:0x29b1460&gt;: undefined method `colorize' for :location:Symbol
(eval):4:in `blue'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/formatters/pretty.rb:22:in `write_command'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/formatters/pretty.rb:10:in `write'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `block in _execute'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:17:in `block (3 levels) in &lt;top (required)&gt;'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
NoMethodError: undefined method `colorize' for :location:Symbol
(eval):4:in `blue'
```

I've set up my release like this:

**deploy.rb**

```ruby
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'myapp.com'
set :user, "deploy"
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:me/myapp.com.git'
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/#{application}'
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :pty, true
```

**Capfile**

```ruby
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
```

**Production.rb**

```ruby
set :location, "myapp.com"
role :app, :location
role :web, :location
role :db,  :location, :primary => true

server 'myapp.com', :roles => [:app, :web, :db], :primary => true
```

**Installed gems and versions:**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
capistrano (3.2.1)
chunky_png (1.2.9)
colorize (0.7.3)
compass (0.12.2)
foundation (1.0.4)
fssm (0.2.10)
i18n (0.6.11)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
minitest (2.5.1)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (2.9.1)
rake (10.3.2, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rubygems-update (2.1.11)
sass (3.2.12)
sshkit (1.5.1)
thor (0.18.1)
```

Does anyone know what to do or how to debug this? I can't find anything from googling... I saw something about colorize gem having to be 0.6+, but as seen above, I have latest (0.7.3 atm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found out: this seems to has to do with version compatibility stuff in the Ruby gems. Found out, it worked on another laptop of mine and then compared configs - working machine was running

> sshkit (1.3.0)

I downgraded sshkit from v. `1.5.1` to `1.3.0`, which solved it.